# Project section in the CV should allow addition of non-public projects

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Passionate developers often have projects that can showcase their abilities best - but are unable to provide URLs to these projects, as they are incomplete or currently on their own systems.

Real talent may lie unnoticed or may get overlooked simply because they do not have publicly visible projects.

Allowing a description of the project, without the URL request, would give recruiters a better handle on the candidate's capability, while at the same time, give talented job seekers a more level playing field.

Comment: How would companies gain knowledge of a developer's talent from a mention of non-public project? It's not like they can look at the code, or the design, or anything else indicative of the level of talent. And I ask this as a consultant whose work is locked behind a number of NDAs and therefore can't legally mention the code I've worked on.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - my suggestion covers work that is not published - and not for work that is restricted for any reason! If the description is attractive, recruiters can always ask to see it. However, if there is no possibility of showcasing - even in description - the CV is, in reality, incomplete....